# Reference is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml, flying-saucer

Please help me to find the reason for this exception ,am using following jars,

```
core-renderer.jar
itext-paulo-155.jar
```

**firstdoc.xhtml**

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"&gt;
&lt;html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt;
    &lt;head&gt;
        &lt;title&gt;My First Document&lt;/title&gt;
        &lt;style type="text/css"&gt; b { color: green; } &lt;/style&gt;
    &lt;/head&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;
            &lt;b&gt;Greetings Earthlings!&lt;/b&gt;
            We've come for your Java.
        &lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
```

**JAVA :**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;

public class Sample1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException, DocumentException {
                String inputFile = "C:/Users/Joseph.M/WorkPlace_Struts2/Fly-Sauccer/src/test/pdf/firstdoc.xhtml";
                String url = new File(inputFile).toURI().toURL().toString();
                String outputFile = "C:/Users/Joseph.M/WorkPlace_Struts2/Fly-Sauccer/src/test/pdf/firstdoc.pdf";
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);             
                ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
                renderer.setDocument(url);
                renderer.layout();
                renderer.createPDF(os);             
                os.close();
    }
}
```

**Exception  :**

```
plumbing.render INFO:: Using CSS implementation from: org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StyleReference
plumbing.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser): com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser
plumbing.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser): com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser
plumbing.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser): com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser
plumbing.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser): com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser
plumbing.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser): com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser
plumbing.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser): com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser
plumbing.load INFO:: Reference is not allowed in prolog.
ERROR:  'Reference is not allowed in prolog.'
plumbing.exception WARNING:: Unhandled exception. Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 2; Reference is not allowed in prolog.
Exception in thread "main" org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 2; Reference is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:191)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource.load(XMLResource.java:71)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.NaiveUserAgent.getXMLResource(NaiveUserAgent.java:118)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.loadDocument(ITextRenderer.java:98)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:102)
    at test.pdf.Sample1.main(Sample1.java:23)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 2; Reference is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:189)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 2; Reference is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use < and > instead of

```
&lt; and &gt;
```

You do not have to escape XML special characters here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't need to use the special characters?

Comment: @EdgeCaseBerg I would expect the SAX parser to take care of proper XML instead of wanting escaped characters. But I don't really know what I'm saying :)

Comment: @EdgeCaseBerg you only need to escape XML special characters when they are used literally inside data in XML elements. If they are used as part of XML syntax (delimiting tags, etc.) they need not be escaped.