# Nashorn: Java Interface

Tags: java, nashorn

Nashorn is a new platform for me, I dont do much with it, but now need to have the following Java line to work to get to InputStream object:

```
InputStream is = IOUtils.toInputStream(body, "UTF-8"); // Java
```

The trouble is IOUtils.toInputStream returns  class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream when it is written as:

```
var is = IOUtils.toInputStream(body, "UTF-8"); //JS in Nashorn
```

I need 'is' var to be InputStream and not anything else to pass it into another Java class. How can I get actual InputStream object on Nashorn platform? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please clarify... May we suppose that the second line is JS?

Comment: `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream` is direct subclass of `java.io.InputStream` which means it inherits all methods and properties of `java.io.InputStream`. So you can just treat `is` like it is an `InputStream`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: I made a comment for clarity, but yes, var line is JS.

Comment: @YosiPramajaya: agree, but while I treat it as InputStream, I get an error on attempt to pass it into another API expecting InputStream, error:   Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Reference is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the `InputStream` implementation type. It's a problem with your markup. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398554/reference-is-not-allowed-in-prolog

Comment: Agree with @erickson your problem is not at the InputStream type. Pay attention to your error trace.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better library to read XML and that works in Nashorn seamlessly:

```
var XmlSlurper = Java.type('groovy.util.XmlSlurper');
var rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(rsp.body); 
var structuredDoc = rootNode.children().getAt(0);
```